# Primefaces - Datatable select all items

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Hi I have a datatable with lazy data loading and a context menu with the option to select/unselect all items. But I have no ideia how make it.

```
<h:form>
    <p:contextMenu for="tableNozzleFamily">  
        <p:menuitem value="#{bundle.global_select_all}" icon="ui-icon-plus"/>
        <p:menuitem value="#{bundle.global_unselect_all}" icon="ui-icon-minus"/>
    </p:contextMenu> 
    <p:dataTable id="tableNozzleFamily" var="nf" value="#{nozzleBean.lazyModel}" paginator="true" rows="20" rowsPerPageTemplate="20, 30, 50" lazy="true" emptyMessage="#{bundle.global_no_data}" selection="#{nozzleBean.selectedNozzleFamilies}">
        <p:columnGroup type="header">
            <p:row>
                <p:column rowspan="2" headerText="#{bundle.global_selection}"/>
                 ...
            </p:row>
        </p:columnGroup>
        <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px"/>
        ...
    </p:dataTable>
```

My enviroment:
Glassfish 3.1.2.2
Mojarra-2.1.11
Primefaces-3.3.1

Answer (score 3):

Did you check primefaces showcase? there is an example that does exactly [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionRadioCheckbox.jsf).

```
<p:dataTable id="multiCars" var="car" value="#{tableBean.mediumCarsModel}" paginator="true" rows="10"  
             selection="#{tableBean.selectedCars}">  

    <f:facet name="header">  
        Checkbox Based Selection  
    </f:facet>  

    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" style="width:18px" />  

    <p:column headerText="Model">  
        #{car.model}  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Year">  
        #{car.year}  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" >  
        #{car.manufacturer}  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Color">  
        #{car.color}  
    </p:column>  

    <f:facet name="footer">  
        <p:commandButton id="multiViewButton" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"  
                         update=":form:displayMulti" oncomplete="multiCarDialog.show()"/>  
    </f:facet>  
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Yes, I had seen this example at primefaces show case, but this example does't do it programmatically. I think that the correct way is to fire an action event at the context menu and at server context select all or make a javascript to select all.

Comment: @AndréAndrade that makes no sense. this is the correct way. you may find other ways, but why to bother when the library already provides you with an implementation? if you need to do an extra processing on server side, you can use ajax event "toogleSelect", which is triggered when header checkbox is toggled

Comment: Because one of the project requirements is to have a context menu with select all/clear selection and some other options. I agree that is much easier use the default solution

Comment: @AndréAndrade if you use a context menu, then do the following to unselect all: call a method in bean that empties the attribute that contains selection and update table.